# How do I turn off Slack's new format while typing?

Tags: slack

After an update, Slack now formats messages as you type them which is highly disruptive to how I type.  How can I disable this feature and only show message formatting after I hit send?

Comment: I sure did like seeing the Markdown format. This _should_ be an option.

Answer (score 10):

Go to *Preferences* -> *Advanced* -> *Input Options* and enable `Format messages with markup`.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: This also disables formatted text from pasting, which is what I was after.

Comment: It also allows you to paste plain with no formatting on mac "Option+Shift+Command+V” - It was so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Slack only recognizes as markdown if you actually type the special character such as ` in Slack. Pasting something with it in it such as: `this is only a test` will not be formatted as code, since typing the ` is the trigger.

So perhaps open a notepad, type what you want, and then copy/paste it into Slack?